# Sql Sum Without Repetition

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Assume, I have two firms Firm 1 and Firm 2 in firm table. Each firm has two projects (Project 1-1 and Project 1-2 belongs Firm 1. Project 2-1 and Project 2-2 belongs Firm 2). Similarly, each project has two expenses (totally 8 expenses). I want to list all firms, total project budget and total expenses of these firms. What does the SQL query (for mysql) look like?

Firm table has two fields (idfirm and name). Project table has four fields (idproject, name, budget and firm_idfirm as foreign key). Finally Expense table has three fields (idexpense, amount and project_idproject as foreign key references to project table's idproject field.)

Firstly I tried this query

```
select firm.name as Firm, sum(project.budget) as Project, sum(expense.amount) as Expense
from firm, project, expense 
where firm.idfirm = project.firm_idfirm and project.idproject = expense.project_idproject
group by firm.name;
```

but its results show that sum of expenses per firm are correct but sum of budgets per firm are not. It seems budgets are duplicated. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  name, pbudget, peamount
from    firm
        inner join
        (select   firm_idfirm, sum(budget) as pbudget, sum(eamount) as peamount
        from      project
                  inner join
                  (select id, sum(amount) as eamount
                  from expense
                  group by project_idproject) e
        on e.project_idproject = project.id
        group by firm_idfirm) p
on firm.id = p.firm_idfirm
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the aggregations in two steps.  There are several ways of expressing this, here is how I'd express it...

```
SELECT
  firm.name as Firm, SUM(project.budget) as budget, SUM (expense.expense) AS expense
FROM
  firm
LEFT JOIN
  project
    ON firm.idfirm = project.firm_idfirm
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT project_idproject, SUM(amount) AS expense FROM expense GROUP BY project_idproject) AS expense
    ON project.idproject = expense.project_idproject
GROUP BY
  firm.name;
```

Comment: Agree almost entirely: I would include `firm.idfirm` in `GROUP BY`. Of course, that would be unnecessary if `firm.name` was supposed to be unique.

Comment: @AndriyM - No, you're right, I was sloppy/lazy and just copied the non-aggregate from the SELECT clause.  MUST group by the PK of a dimension table as a matter of principle.

Answer (score 0):

As for **why** the `budget` sum is wrong, imagine the query results without `sum` or `group by`.  The `project.budget` value is repeated for every related `expense` record, but `sum` does not account for that.  It just adds them all blindly, inflating the sum.